# How add watermark to ghostscript with command line?

Tags: pdf, ghostscript, watermark

Is any way to add watermark on each pdf with command line? because I need set up params from code

`'gs -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -q -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile="7ed753c56994067cb0c8dc18fbf14921.pdf" "b79d2282c15b7e824cb8ee400401161d.pdf" "f21958c0b3a4a01fe22c9a60b6e15121.pdf" "d46615b5dd7b6e6565ef1ce8b117b860.pdf" "f46ea9512f5763693c84d8061eeff742.pdf"'`

I just need setup path to watermark, opacity, position x,y and width\height

Answer (score 7):

If you can afford using just text instead of an image for watermarking, then you can simulate watermark with 'setlinewidth stroke'.

Just create a mark.ps file like below:

```
<<
   /EndPage
   {
     2 eq { pop false }
     {
         gsave      
         /Helvetica findfont 48 scalefont setfont
         newpath
         .90 setgray 130 70 moveto 50 rotate
         (${watermark}) false  charpath
         1 setlinewidth stroke
         grestore
         true
     } ifelse
   } bind
>> setpagedevice
```

And then run:

```
gs -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -q -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=watermarked.pdf mark.ps original.pdf
```

I have made this and other features like password protection, search, split and merge available from a plain old bash (POB) open source CLI project in github called [pdf-bash-tools](https://github.com/nestoru/pdf-bash-tools).

Comment: Interesting solution. Unfortunately the syntax is a little bit archaic and that particular font did not work for my system. Do you think you could add an addition to your answer in showing how to use a font such as the Hack font?

Answer (score 0):

The only way to add content to each page is going to be to use PostScript to do it for you. Adding a custom EndPage procedure will allow you to place marks on the rendered page bitmap (or in the case of pdfwrite, append to the page content stream) immediately before the page is finalised.

PostScript does not support transparency, so you cannot immediately use PostScript to achieve 'opacity'. However, Ghostscript does support the pdfmark operator, and for PDF output **only** it is possible to use this.

So what you need to do is write an EndPage procedure which uses a pdfmark to draw an annotation on the page. The appearance stream for the annotation will contain the drawing operations for the 'watermark'. If you want the appearance to involve transparency you may well need to add a transparency group but that can be done with a pdfmark as well.

Comment: ok, can you say how put image with position to postscript for watermark? or pdf containing watermark

Comment: You need the 'image' operator, which is described in section 4.10 (page 288) of the 3rd edition PostScript Language Reference Manual. Also page 607 describes the operator. The position of the image is given by the current point, modified by the Tx and Ty members of the Matrix supplied to the image operator.